# Possible to change object referenced in with statement but retain context functionality?

Tags: python, with-statement

I am attempting to find a way to use the `with` statement to open one of several large database files. One can assume for the purpose of this question that we want to ensure that the file is closed once it is no longer needed because there is a limit to the number of database files that can be opened at once by the underlying library.

The database files are read with a particular class, say `Database`, which does not read all database contents upon instantiation, but instead just reads metadata about the database. This metadata is used to determine whether the database is valid or not. (FYI) Only if particular data is requested does it interrogate the (opened) file further.

Here is a minimal example of how this might be encoded *without* the `with` context:

```
file='file1.dh'         # don't read into the extension; it's just an example
dataobj=Database(file)  # Database was created specifically to read files of .dh extension
if not dataobj.isvalid:
  dataobj.close()
  file='file2.dh'
  dataobj=Database(file)

# ... then proceed with remainder of calculation
# and finally...

databoj.close()
```

The `Database` class has necessary `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to allow it to be used within the `with` construct, and this is desirable. For example (pseudo-code):

```
class Database():
  def __init__(self,file):
    self.read_metadata()
  def read_metadata(self):
    # ... read metadata from file
  def close(self):
    # ... do some necessary cleanup and disconnect from underlying database reader
  def __enter__(self):
    return self
  def __exit__(self,typ,value,traceback):
    self.close()
```

The real motivation behind this question is - because it takes a long time even to read metadata from these large files - it is very undesirable (1) to open the first valid file found more than once, or (2) to have to open more files than necessary (i.e. resources should not be wasted on opening multiple files).

It is hoped that, once a valid file is found, we can proceed with that file opened within the `with` context. One can generically see that this can be extended to an indefinite number of files, but this is not necessary for this question.

For example, using the `with` statement, we could write

```
with Database('file1.dh') as dh:
  if dh.isvalid:
    file='file1.dh'
  else:
    file='file2.dh'
with Database(file) as dh:
  # ...proceed with calculation
```

This requires that `file1.dh` is opened twice *when it is valid*.

Can it be avoided while still using the `with` statement? Please also feel free to suggest something that I may not be aware of (i.e. I don't want to exclude possible approaches that do not use `with` but still retain context manager functionality).

I will throw another wrench into the works... at the moment, the second file 'file2.dh' is not known (it is computed), and it is *preferred* to keep it that way (i.e. some computation can be saved by not knowing even the identity of the second file if it is not needed.. if the first file is found to be valid).

I will place here an example pseudo-code of, conceptually, what I would like to achieve:

```
with FirstValidFile('file1.dh','file2.dh') as dh:
  # ... do all computation
```

where `file2.dh` replaces dh if `file1.dh` is not valid, otherwise the calculation proceeds with `file1.dh`.

I imagine the following would work, but is it ideal, or is there another way? Is there a way to retain `with` construct around `Database` objects individually, so that if there is an exception the cleanup will be done?

```
class FirstValidFile():
  def __init__(self,*potential_files):
    for file in potential_files:
      dh=Database(file)
      if dh.isvalid:
        self.dh=dh
        return
      dh.close()

  def __enter__(self):
    return self.dh
  def __exit__(self,a,b,c):
    self.dh.__exit__(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a flag and throw it in a `while` loop. You can also do an infinite loop with a `break` statement if you prefer but I think it's slightly less maintainable.

```py
file = 'file1.dh'
valid_file_found= False
while not valid_file_found:
    with Database(file) as dh:
        if dh.isvalid:
            # do calculations
            valid_file_found= True
        else:
            file = # calculate file name
```

Comment: Wow. I really had that all backward. I would prefer the `break`/`continue` approach, but that's just to avoid excess indentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this one is rather simple: all you need to do is to place all the initial code that determines the chosen database object into a function, and that returns the "winner". As that is then the actual context manager object, you'll retain the wanted properties.

As a simplified concept:

```
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Database:

    name: str

    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__", self)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("__exit__", self)

def chose_database(*args):
    return Database(random.choice(args))


with chose_database("foo", "bar", "baz") as db:
    print("the chosen db", db)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the function that determines which file to use is the crux here. The way you have it you'd have to open the file twice: once to determine it's valid, and again thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

After considering further, I'll suggest an answer as a twist on the solution I suggested in my question. Use inheritance from the `Database` class to fully couple the final return value of `__enter__` to the desired `Database` object, but through the `super` function.

```
class FirstValidFile(Database):
  def __init__(self,*potential_files):
    for file in potential_files:
      super().__init__(self,file)
      if self.isvalid:
        return
      self.close()
```

This fulfills all requirements. There is still the potential that an exception is raised during instantiation, but that exists anyway.

I'm still interested to see if anyone has a better alternative.